# Can't run Watch and iPhone Simulator at the same time

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I'm trying to send messages between an Apple Watch and an iPhone, using WatchConnectivity. But I can't run the app in both simulators simultaneously. I put a `print` in both `viewDidLoad` from iOS and `awake(withContext:)` from Watch, but only the second one is printed. It launches both devices, but my application is just opened in the watch.

[image: screenshot of Xcode, Apple Watch simulator, and iPhone simulator]

Does anyone have an idea about the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can debug both instances at the same time by the following steps.

- Launch the watch instance from Xcode so it's connected to the watch simulator
- Switch the target to phone app.
- Go to Debug -> Attach to Process -> Select the phone app.

Put breakpoints on both either app and they will both stop.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you! But, just to add, I didn't even had to switch the target, just to attach to the phone app process!

Comment: I followed your instruction to transfer file from watch simulator to iPhone simulator, watch simulator showed success but iphone did not receive anything.